# gcc function attribute to do something on function entry & exit

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm-clang

There are lots of gcc attributes one can assign to variables/functions these days. I have gone through the gcc documentation and I haven't found what I am looking for -- or may be I missed it. Hence the question.

What I am looking for is some mechanism when using gcc, that a function 'X' be called when function 'f' enters and function 'Y' be called when function 'f' exits. Basically I have lot of code currently that does following and I am wondering if the LOCK/UNLOCK could be done "automatically" through some kind of attribute.

```
f() {

LOCK_RESOURCE();

UNLOCK_RESOURCE();

}
```

Comment: You could compile that file in C++ mode and use struct constructors/destructors.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`__attribute__((cleanup))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bcleanup_007d-attribute-3213):

> The cleanup attribute runs a function when the variable goes out of scope. This attribute can only be applied to auto function scope variables; it may not be applied to parameters or variables with static storage duration. The function must take one parameter, a pointer to a type compatible with the variable. The return value of the function (if any) is ignored.